# The garden balsam doesn't seem as healthy and fresh as it used to be

Tags: leaves, plant-care, bugs, spider-mites

It's been a few days since we noticed something like a spider web and a few semi-bugs living  on the leafs. The store where I bought it from was a big greenhouse and they warned us to keep it away from direct sunlight but as I googled to learn more about its soil requirements and watering frequency, it turned out it needs full sunlight. Please give me some accurate information about this Plant. What's wrong with it? How to save it?

[image]

Comment: Do you have another, botanical name for your plant rather than just 'balsam'? It looks like some kind of Impatiens, but its hard to tell... are you keeping it indoors? What part of the world are you in?

Comment: @Bamboo, leave me alone and touch me not were other names I found by googling the picture. A small greenhouse we made in our balcony, it's slightly warmer than inside and outside the house. We live in Istanbul.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think we'll have to go with my first guess of Impatiens - Impatiens hawkerii, commonly known as Impatiens New Guinea hybrids - Impatiens are sometimes referred to as balsam.  That is vaguely what it looks like...

They like half a day's sun, not full sun and need regular feeding and watering in pots. They are frost sensitive and often grown as annuals for a summer display in colder regions of the world, though they can be kept as houseplants in the right conditions. Yours appears to have an infestation or two of something, probably spider mite plus possibly some other insect problem, as well as maybe some early fungal trouble. I suggest you go and seek out a good, systemic insecticide spray that treats for aphids, scale and spider mite as a start. Spray according to the instructions, and I think it might be better if the plant could be either indoors in sun, or outdoors if its warm enough in part shade, rather than being contained in a greenhouse, where fungal problems may readily occur. Further info and images here (though they always show them in flower) https://homeguides.sfgate.com/care-new-guinea-impatiens-43324.html